# react router exact path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to set up routes using React Router.

I have a First component, which is the first component you see. And I have a Second component, which is linked to from inside the First component.

```
<Route path="/Second" component={Second}/>
```

Without the first route, it works fine, except when I click on the link to the Second component the First component remains visible, as expected.

So when I try to add a route with an exact path to the First component, like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={First}/>
```

the entire app stops functioning. It just says "Waiting for localhost...", and the page becomes unresponsive. If I remove that path it works again. I can't even connect to the React developer tools.

Is this possibly because I'm linking to the First component from within the component?

And I do have the routes nested in a Switch.

Comment: What does your `First` and `Second` components look like? Could you include that in the question?

Comment: Please post larger snippets of your code and/or console or bundler errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get the Problem here. For me this worked fine: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/l3ll9z4yw7

Maybe you can explain it with more code, or did it solved your issue?